# composer package only for development in laravel providers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If I have a package (that I have to add to `app/config/app.php` providers/aliases) that I only really want on my development boxes (b/c I only use for development)  is there an approach that will allow me to do this leveraging `composer require --dev <package>`  along w/ `composer install --no-dev`

I need to add an index into both the providers and aliases array...but I would **prefer NOT** to manage those large arrays in multiple config environment folders if possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a folder in your `config` directory that matches your environment name.  `dev` in this case.

Next, recreate any files you wish to override and place them into that folder. `app.php` in this case

Next open `bootstrap/start.php` and find `$app->detectEnvironment`.  The array passed to this method determines which environment you are working with.  Setting the key to this array as `dev` will overwrite any of your config files with their counterparts in your `dev` folder.

If you do not wish to create an entirely new providers array in `app.php` file for each environment and say you only wanted to add a certain provider to your `dev` environment, you may use a helper method like so...

```
'providers' => append_config(array(
    'DevOnlyServiceProvider',
))
```

All this information was pulled from the Laravel documentation found here: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking how to do this in Laravel 5, you can still emulate the L4 behaviour.

On the top of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` add:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
```

And then edit the register() method:

```
public function register()
{

    $path = $this->app->environment() .'.app';
    $config = $this->app->make('config');
    $aliasLoader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

    if ($config->has($path)) {
        array_map([$this->app, 'register'], $config->get($path .'.providers'));

        foreach ($config->get($path .'.aliases') as $key => $class) {
            $aliasLoader->alias($key, $class);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add `config/<YOUR ENVIRONMENT NAME>/app.php` config file and define additional providers and aliases, same as in app.php

For example:

```
return [

    'providers' => [
        Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    'aliases' => [
        'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
    ],

];
```